# Geometry textbooks from the 1800s

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, reference-request

I was reading this [paper](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/CUPM/pdf/MAAUndergradHistory.pdf) recently and noticed that the college mathematics curriculum included geometry and trigonometry.  It might be a poor assumption, but I'm assuming that geometry (or trigonometry) was taught at a much higher level than it is taught today.  I was wondering if there is a comprehensive list of books or references that would shed some light on the types of problems that they had to work it.

Comment: It is not a poor assumption, unfortunately...

Comment: I've tried googling, I'm getting to the point where I don't know what to search for.  My searches have yielded today's geometry textbooks.

Comment: This website may have some information http://digital.library.pitt.edu/cgi-bin/t/text/text-idx?idno=00aep6689m&view=toc&c=nietz

Comment: For searching, go to google-books and date-restrict the search to the 19th century (or pick whatever range of years you want), and search using key words such as "geometry", "review", "college", "trigonometry", "analytic geometry", "conics", etc. Many of the hits will be advertisements or publishers announcements or textbook listings in various journals and also at the back of other textbooks, and these lists will give you a huge number of books that you can search for and look at. I personally have separate folders of over 100 downloaded textbooks from the 1800s for each of several subjects.

Comment: For searching, it helps to know the popular authors (such as Spivak, Rudin, Halmos, etc. for the present time for more advanced subjects). In the case of trigonometry, some popular authors are Isaac Todhunter, Ernest William Hobson, Clement Vavasor Durell and Alan Robson (co-authors), Elias Loomis, Émile Gelin, John Casey, Joseph Alfred Serret, Sidney Luxton Loney. All of these authors wrote textbooks on other subjects also, for example see [Loney's books](https://archive.org/search.php?query=creator%3A%22Sidney+Luxton+Loney%22).

Comment: "Heavenly mathematics" by Glen van Brummellen has a list of spherical trigonometry  (and is a nice reading book as well) BTW between 1800 and 1899 geometry changed a whole lot (from Euclidean synthetic geometry to analytic coordinate geometry, to name just one)